# How can I deactivate a single Live Templates in Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

For example: I don't like the "prop" Live Template of R# and want to use the Visual Studio Snippet, like i did before I installed R#.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Workaround by @gorohoroh:

Press TAB twice after specifying keywords in template placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

Go to ReSharper > Live Templates > C#, and deselect "prop"

Comment: So what you actually want to do is deploy the VS snippet from ReSharper completion list? If that's what you want, it's not possible unless you switch off ReSharper IntelliSense completely in ReSharper options. Another way would be to press Ctrl+K+X and invoke the snippet from VS snippet catalog. Finally, you can tell me exactly what you don't like in ReSharper snippet and we'll see how to modify it to match your requirements.

Comment: I like the the prop-Snippet of VS because it's behavior: I type "prop" > **TAB**: marks the datatype > **TAB**: marks the variable name. With another **TAB** it marks the datatype again, with **ENTER** I can write the next property

Comment: With R# templates, you type TAB to go to type, TAB to switch to prop name, and TAB once again to complete template deployment. Why do you need to switch to type for the second time?

Comment: R# does not mark the property name after I typed the datatype. It positions the cursor before the suggested name by R#. The suggested name is "Type" most of the time. If I don't want this as the property name I have to hit **DEL** four times before I can start typing.

Comment: This is strange. Here's how this template is deployed in ReSharper 5.1.3: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UARgl-3RkrI - with 3*Tabs. Which ReSharper version are you using?

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks to your Video I found a regularity. It works with R#, as long as you don't use a keyword as datatype.For example string, int, double etc. don't work. But String, Int32, Double etc. do work.

Comment: What do I have to change, that the Live Template expects both a Type OR a keyword as the property's datatype?

Comment: Bingo! I can confirm this is a bug, and it's registered at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-79895. Many thanks for helping define it. The bug will be fixed in ReSharper 6. Current workaround: press TAB twice after specifying keywords in template placeholders.

Comment: Well.. I understand your irony but it's the best I can offer before the bug is fixed.

Comment: No Irony. It's great! It's a true relief compared to the behavior before. I always hated to delete the produced "Type"-Suffix for the most properties. When creating POCO's, it really kills the writing flow.

Comment: I still have this problem with the latest resharper and cant understand why the press tab twice is a solution, it still give me the undesired effect.