# ReSharper - How to revert back to Visual Studio code templates

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, code-snippets, code-templates

When creating a property in Visual Studio, I use the snippet `prop` and can <kbd>TAB</kbd> between the type and the name and Visual Studio jumps between the 2.

ReSharper has taken over this functionality, and I would like to know how to reset it back to Visual Studio. The problem I have is I don't know where to look. In Visual Studio 2012 I can see a ReSharper menu, but there are so many options I don't know where to look.

Comment: hi, think you can use [reset to default settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820049/resharper-confused-my-visual-studio-reset-visual-studio-with-defaults) option?

Comment: Thank you but I would not want to reset everything though, although if there are no other options it may be a solution!

Comment: I think you will find that Resharper's Live Templates override Visual Studio's (inferior) Snippets. Maybe you can rename the Resharper one and it will go back to using the VS one. Why do you not like the Resharper `prop` Live Template?

Comment: then you should check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800954/how-can-i-deactivate-a-single-live-templates-in-resharper) out, as it is an exact duplicate of your issue.

Comment: When you install ReSharper it imports the existing snippets, I believe. Is this not the case?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk - The issue isn't that it doesn't import them, it's that it behaves differently. For example, in VS type prop and then double tab. Then press tab another 6 times and you'll see the selection jump back and forth. Resharper doesn't allow this back and forth.

Comment: @BeytanKurt - Thank you, I will look into this, as this looks very promising.

Answer (score 1):

In ReSharper 9.2 in Visual Studio 2015, I achieved this by doing the following:

1. Going to the `ReSharper -> Tools -> Templates Explorer...` menu
2. Deleting all templates in all scopes in all three of the `Live Templates`, `Surround Templates` and `File Templates` tabs. To speed this up, I was able to select all templates in a scope by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then delete them by pressing the `X` button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation with Visual Studio 2013 and ReSharper 9. I simply went to menu ReSharper → *Tools* → *Templates Explorer* and then found the prop template and removed it.

You can also deselect templates as well which may work, but I didn't try that approach.